# Stop compilation when a template has been used/resolved

Tags: c++, gcc, pragma

This MCVE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH_DATETIME 25

template <typename T>
char * convertUnixTimeToChar( time_t unixTime, T )
{
    (void) unixTime;
    #pragma message "2nd parameter in convertUnixTimeToChar() must be of type <char [MAX_LENGTH_DATETIME]>."
    exit(1);
};

template<size_t N>
char * convertUnixTimeToChar( time_t unixTime, char (&destination) [N] )
{
    if ( N < MAX_LENGTH_DATETIME )
    {
        printf( "Overflow in convertUnixTimeToChar(): destination size [%ld] must be at least [%u]", N, MAX_LENGTH_DATETIME );
        exit(1);
    }
    struct tm * tmNow;
    tmNow = localtime( &unixTime );
    strftime( destination, MAX_LENGTH_DATETIME - 1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tmNow );
    return destination;
};

int main()
{
    char buffer [MAX_LENGTH_DATETIME ];
    printf( "Converted unix time=%s\n", convertUnixTimeToChar( 1487585045, buffer ) );
}
```

**My question:**

I would like to get displayed the message `#pragma message "2nd parameter in convertUnixTimeToChar() must be of type <char [MAX_LENGTH_DATETIME]>."` **from** gcc while the compilation **only when** a variable of type `char *` has been passed to `convertUnixTimeToChar()` because the 1st template was resolved. Now I get always this message.

In other words, the compilation should fail if a wrong parameter is passed and not when the program is running [in this case I have to use a `printf` instead of `#pragma` to get notified].

Passing something like `char [25]` resolves the 2nd template and all is fine!

Is there a way I can stop conditionally the compilation with an error message in case a template has been used *physically* for the code generation?

Compiled with gcc 4.9.4 using these switches: `-Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++11 -O3`

Comment: Why not just remove the catch-all overload?

Comment: @Quentin OMG. Yes, in this case I get an error message from the compiler `error: no matching function for call to ‘convertUnixTimeToChar(int, char*&)’` and `note:   mismatched types ‘char [N]’ and ‘char*’`- Even it is not 100% what I wanted but it satisfies my needs. Write your comment as an answer and I accept it! May be I wanted a very clear message but the compiler error is also clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once more, the optimal solution is "don't do anything at all".
Removing the catch-all overload altogether will make the compiler produce an error for any parameter that cannot match `char (&destination) [N]`.

If you want to get fancy and add your own error message, you can use a dependent `static_assert` inside the catch-all:

```
template <class..., class T>
constexpr T &&depend(T &&o) {
    return std::forward<T>(o);
}

template <typename T>
char *convertUnixTimeToChar( time_t, T&& )
{
    static_assert(depend<T>(false), "2nd parameter in convertUnixTimeToChar() must ...");
}
```

Not that this is probably not a *better* solution, because you grab the whole overload set for `convertUnixTimeToChar` and sink it into a hard error, SFINAE be damned. If someone want to add overloads for their own types, they will have to make sure theirs are a better match than this explosive catch-all, which is more pain than gain.